# Is it possible to configure the resolution of `CameraCaptureTask` in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

Is there a way to configure the resolution of a `CameraCaptureTask` in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with current SDK. It's up to user to select the resolution while taking a snap.

You can however scale/crop the returned image to your needed resolution.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing now, but I was hoping to save the user's time (and battery).